# How to load large list of data to SQL table for single row using python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sql-server, list

I tried some methods to load large list of comma-separated data to a  table for single column.

I'm facing error while loading list of data to SQL

Here is the error:

> cur.execute(sql, val)
> psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: column "word_exclusion" is of type character varying but expression is of type text[]

You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

My data is looks like Below and I tried below method:

```
    eng_stopwords =['further', 'then', 'once', 'here', 'there', 'when', 'where', 'why', 'how', 'all', 'any', 'both', 'ea
ch', 'few', 'more', 'most', 'other', 'some', 'such', 'no', 'nor', 'not', 'only', 'own', 'same', 'so', 'than', 'too', 'very', 's
', 't', 'can', 'will', 'just', 'don', "don't", 'should', "should've", 'now', 'd', 'll', 'm', 'o', 're', 've', 'y', 'ain', 'aren
', "aren't", 'couldn', "couldn't", 'didn', "didn't", 'doesn', "doesn't", 'hadn', "hadn't", 'hasn', "hasn't", 'haven', "haven't"
, 'isn', "isn't", 'ma', 'mightn', "mightn't", 'mustn', "mustn't", 'needn', "needn't", 'shan', "shan't", 'shouldn', "shouldn't",
 'wasn', "wasn't", 'weren', "weren't", 'won', "won't", 'wouldn', "wouldn't"]
  cur = conn.cursor ()
  today = date.today()
sql = "INSERT INTO oey_stg.shc_spit_wod_exsions (word_exclusion, load_date) VALUES (%s,%s)"
val =  (eng_stopwords,today)
cur.execute(sql, val)
```

In the table `word_exclusion` is a single column so I want load the eng_stopwords to word_exclusion column and load_date is today variable.

I tried some casting method ::varchar but got same error.

Comment: `execute()` can create only one row. For more rows you should use `executemany()` but it may need to create list with repeated `today` because it will need two lists with the same number of data (rows). OR you should use `for`-loop and insert every work separately with `execute()`.

Comment: facing this issue now TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: it may need to convert `today` to `string`

Comment: What library are you using? %s implies pymssql, rather than pyodbc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execute()` can create only one row. For more rows you should use `executemany()` but it may need to create list with repeated `today` because it will need two lists with the same number of data (rows).

And it may need to create list of tuples `[(word1, today), (word2, today), etc.]`

```
eng_stopwords = [...]
today = date.today()

many_todays = [today] * len(eng_stopwords)  # repeat date for every row

sql = "INSERT INTO oey_stg.shc_spit_wod_exsions (word_exclusion, load_date) VALUES (%s,%s)"

data = zip(eng_stopwords, many_todays)

cur.executemany(sql, data)
```

Or you should use `for`-loop and insert every work separately with execute()

```
eng_stopwords = [...]
today = date.today()  # single value which it will put in all rows

sql = "INSERT INTO oey_stg.shc_spit_wod_exsions (word_exclusion, load_date) VALUES (%s,%s)"

for word in eng_stopwords:
    cur.execute(sql, (word, today))
```

It may need to convert `today` from `datetime`  to `string`

```
today = today.strftime('%Y-%M-%D')
```

Comment: Thanks for answering just curious about can i add data to single column in db not row by row

Comment: you have `executemany()` for this. But it needs to create list with value for every row.

Answer (score 1):

You could put your list and value for today into a tuple and then use `executemany`. This uses parameter markers, rather than `%s` injection, as I use pyodbc in my home environment:

```py
eng_stopwords =['further', 'then', 'once', 'here', 'there', 'when', 'where', 'why', 'how', 'all', 'any', 'both', 'each', 'few', 'more', 'most', 'other', 'some', 'such', 'no', 'nor', 'not', 'only', 'own', 'same', 'so', 'than', 'too', 'very', 's', 't', 'can', 'will', 'just', 'don', "don't", 'should', "should've", 'now', 'd', 'll', 'm', 'o', 're', 've', 'y', 'ain', 'aren', "aren't", 'couldn', "couldn't", 'didn', "didn't", 'doesn', "doesn't", 'hadn', "hadn't", 'hasn', "hasn't", 'haven', "haven't", 'isn', "isn't", 'ma', 'mightn', "mightn't", 'mustn', "mustn't", 'needn', "needn't", 'shan', "shan't", 'shouldn', "shouldn't",'wasn', "wasn't", 'weren', "weren't", 'won', "won't", 'wouldn', "wouldn't"]
today = date.today()
params = [(eng_stopwords[i],today) for i in range (0,len(eng_stopwords))]


with pyodbc.connect(SQLConnString,timeout=20) as sqlConn:
    with sqlConn.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.shc_spit_wod_exsions (word_exclusion, load_date) VALUES (?,?)"
        cursor.executemany(sql, params)
```